# Locked myself out of SSH, Plesk access available

Tags: ssh, plesk, ufw

Somehow I seem to manage to close port 22 on my Ubuntu Server via ufw.

I still can access the server via the plesk interface (so 8443 seems to be open).

I can NOT access the Plesk Upgrades (port 8447) where I could install the plesk firewall to solve the issue with port 22.

I was searching to find a solution how to open port 22 on ufw via plesk, but everthing I found directed me to "open a SSH connection" or "install the plesk firewall".

What are my options? Can I create a script which opens port 22 and execute it via plesk somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!

In Plesk, go to Tools&Settings -> Schedule a task -> Add Task -> Choose "run a command" and as command you insert "/usr/sbin/ufw allow 22" (if your ufw is in that folder).

Make sure the system user is set to root.

Click on "Run Now".

The task should execute sucessfully, and the connection via SSH should be available again.